# org.springframework.web.HttpRequestMethodNotSupportedException: Request method 'POST' is not supported

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, thymeleaf

I am working on the login module of my `Java`, `Springboot`, `React` and `Thymeleaf` application and I am encountering `org.springframework.web.HttpRequestMethodNotSupportedException: Request method 'POST' is not supported` when I submit the HTML login form. Not sure how to proceed. I have gone through similar posts but it did not help me resolve the issue.

**Project Structure**

[image: Project Structure]

**login.html**

```
<!--<div th:if="${param.error}">Invalid username and/or password.</div>-->
<form action="#" th:action="@{/validateLogin}" method="post" th:object="${userInfo}" class="row g-4">
   <div class="col-12">
      <label>Username<span class="text-danger">*</span></label>
      <div class="input-group">
         <div class="input-group-text"><i class="bi bi-person-fill"></i></div>
         <label>
         <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter Username" th:field="*{username}">
         </label>
      </div>
   </div>
   <div class="col-12">
      <label>Password<span class="text-danger">*</span></label>
      <div class="input-group">
         <div class="input-group-text"><i class="bi bi-lock-fill"></i></div>
         <label>
         <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter Password" th:field="*{password}">
         </label>
      </div>
   </div>
   <div class="col-sm-6">
      <div class="form-check">
         <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" id="inlineFormCheck">
         <label class="form-check-label" for="inlineFormCheck">Remember me</label>
      </div>
   </div>
   <div class="col-sm-6">
      <a href="#" class="float-end text-primary">Forgot Password?</a>
   </div>
   <div class="col-12">
      <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary px-4 float-end mt-4">login</button>
   </div>
</form>
```

**AuthenticationController**

```
import in.sandeep.campusconvene.model.Users;
import org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.*;

@Controller
public class AuthenticationController {

    @RequestMapping(path = "/validateLogin", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public String validateLogin(@ModelAttribute Users userInfo){
        return userInfo.getUsername ();
    }
}
```

**Exception Stacktrace**

```
Whitelabel Error Page
This application has no explicit mapping for /error, so you are seeing this as a fallback.

Fri Oct 13 09:15:25 IST 2023
There was an unexpected error (type=Method Not Allowed, status=405).
Method 'POST' is not supported.
org.springframework.web.HttpRequestMethodNotSupportedException: Request method 'POST' is not supported
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.support.WebContentGenerator.checkRequest(WebContentGenerator.java:381)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.AbstractController.handleRequest(AbstractController.java:164)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.SimpleControllerHandlerAdapter.handle(SimpleControllerHandlerAdapter.java:51)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:1081)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:974)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:1011)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:914)
    at jakarta.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:590)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:885)
    at jakarta.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:658)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:205)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:149)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:51)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:174)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:149)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:100)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:116)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:174)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:149)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.FormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(FormContentFilter.java:93)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:116)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:174)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:149)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:201)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:116)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:174)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:149)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:167)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:90)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:482)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:115)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:93)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:74)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:341)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:391)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:63)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:894)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1740)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:52)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1191)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:659)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:833)
```

I am expecting to retrieve the `username` and `password` from the `login.html` and authenticate the user and route it to appropriate landing pages.

**EDIT 1:**

I have updated the code as below, removed the `AuthenticationController` class and created a `RoutingController` class which implements `org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.error.ErrorController` and `org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.WebMvcConfigurer`.

```
import in.sandeep.campusconvene.model.Users;
import jakarta.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.error.ErrorController;
import org.springframework.core.Ordered;
import org.springframework.http.HttpStatus;
import org.springframework.ui.Model;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.*;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.ViewControllerRegistry;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.WebMvcConfigurer;

@RestController
public class RoutingController implements ErrorController, WebMvcConfigurer {

    private static final String MAIN_APPLICATION_PATH = "/";
    private static final String LOGIN_VALIDATOR_PATH = "/validateLogin";
    private static final String ERROR_PATH = "/error";

    @Override
    public void addViewControllers(ViewControllerRegistry registry) {
        registry.addViewController(MAIN_APPLICATION_PATH)
                .setViewName("forward:/login.html");
        registry.setOrder(Ordered.HIGHEST_PRECEDENCE);
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = ERROR_PATH)
    public String handleError(HttpServletRequest request) {
        Integer statusCode = (Integer) request.getAttribute("javax.servlet.error.status_code");
        Exception exception = (Exception) request.getAttribute("javax.servlet.error.exception");
        return String.format("<html><body><h2>Error Page</h2><div>Status code: <b>%s</b></div>" +
                        "<div>Exception Message: <b>%s</b></div><body></html>",
                statusCode, exception == null ? "N/A" : exception.getMessage());
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = LOGIN_VALIDATOR_PATH, method = RequestMethod.POST)
    @ResponseStatus(value= HttpStatus.OK)
    public String validateLogin(@RequestBody Users users, Model model){
        System.out.println ("INSIDE validateLogin.....");
        return "LET'S AUTHENTICATE";
    }
}
```

Now, when I am trying to submit the form, this is what I encounter on the browser and on the console respectively. It's not even reaching the `validateLogin` method.

Need help on how to get this sorted.

[image: Error Page]

```
2023-10-14T12:17:15.890+05:30 DEBUG 10130 --- [nio-8080-exec-3] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : POST "/", parameters={masked}
2023-10-14T12:17:15.891+05:30 DEBUG 10130 --- [nio-8080-exec-3] o.s.w.s.handler.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping  : Mapped to ParameterizableViewController [view="forward:/login.html"]
2023-10-14T12:17:15.901+05:30  WARN 10130 --- [nio-8080-exec-3] .w.s.m.s.DefaultHandlerExceptionResolver : Resolved [org.springframework.web.HttpRequestMethodNotSupportedException: Request method 'POST' is not supported]
2023-10-14T12:17:15.901+05:30 DEBUG 10130 --- [nio-8080-exec-3] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Completed 405 METHOD_NOT_ALLOWED
2023-10-14T12:17:15.902+05:30 DEBUG 10130 --- [nio-8080-exec-3] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : "ERROR" dispatch for POST "/error", parameters={masked}
2023-10-14T12:17:15.904+05:30 DEBUG 10130 --- [nio-8080-exec-3] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping : Mapped to in.sandeep.campusconvene.controller.RoutingController#handleError(HttpServletRequest)
2023-10-14T12:17:15.927+05:30 DEBUG 10130 --- [nio-8080-exec-3] m.m.a.RequestResponseBodyMethodProcessor : Using 'text/html', given [text/html, application/xhtml+xml, image/avif, image/webp, image/apng, application/xml;q=0.9, */*;q=0.8, application/signed-exchange;v=b3;q=0.7] and supported [text/plain, */*, application/json, application/*+json]
2023-10-14T12:17:15.928+05:30 DEBUG 10130 --- [nio-8080-exec-3] m.m.a.RequestResponseBodyMethodProcessor : Writing ["<html><body><h2>Error Page</h2><div>Status code: <b>null</b></div><div>Exception Message: <b>N/A</b> (truncated)..."]
2023-10-14T12:17:15.930+05:30 DEBUG 10130 --- [nio-8080-exec-3] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Exiting from "ERROR" dispatch, status 405
```

**EDIT 2:**

With the current version of `validateLogin` method

```
@RequestMapping(value = LOGIN_VALIDATOR_PATH, method = RequestMethod.POST)
@ResponseStatus(value = HttpStatus.OK)
public String validateLogin(HttpServletRequest request) {
  String username = request.getParameter("username");
  String password = request.getParameter("password");
  return username + password;
}
```

I am now getting a response as expected on the API Tester as well as on the console as below

```
2023-10-14T23:24:50.091+05:30 DEBUG 7663 --- [nio-8080-exec-3] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : POST "/validateLogin", parameters={masked}
2023-10-14T23:24:50.091+05:30 DEBUG 7663 --- [nio-8080-exec-3] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping : Mapped to in.sandeep.campusconvene.controller.RoutingController#validateLogin(HttpServletRequest)
2023-10-14T23:24:50.093+05:30 DEBUG 7663 --- [nio-8080-exec-3] m.m.a.RequestResponseBodyMethodProcessor : Using 'text/plain', given [*/*] and supported [text/plain, */*, application/json, application/*+json]
2023-10-14T23:24:50.093+05:30 DEBUG 7663 --- [nio-8080-exec-3] m.m.a.RequestResponseBodyMethodProcessor : Writing ["user1 foo"]
2023-10-14T23:24:50.094+05:30 DEBUG 7663 --- [nio-8080-exec-3] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Completed 200 OK
```

[image: API Tester]

But when I am trying to submit the form through the browser, I still encounter `405 METHOD_NOT_ALLOWED`

```
2023-10-14T23:28:30.723+05:30 DEBUG 7663 --- [io-8080-exec-10] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : POST "/", parameters={masked}
2023-10-14T23:28:30.724+05:30 DEBUG 7663 --- [io-8080-exec-10] o.s.w.s.handler.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping  : Mapped to ParameterizableViewController [view="forward:/login.html"]
2023-10-14T23:28:30.724+05:30  WARN 7663 --- [io-8080-exec-10] .w.s.m.s.DefaultHandlerExceptionResolver : Resolved [org.springframework.web.HttpRequestMethodNotSupportedException: Request method 'POST' is not supported]
2023-10-14T23:28:30.724+05:30 DEBUG 7663 --- [io-8080-exec-10] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Completed 405 METHOD_NOT_ALLOWED
2023-10-14T23:28:30.725+05:30 DEBUG 7663 --- [io-8080-exec-10] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : "ERROR" dispatch for POST "/error", parameters={masked}
2023-10-14T23:28:30.725+05:30 DEBUG 7663 --- [io-8080-exec-10] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping : Mapped to in.sandeep.campusconvene.controller.RoutingController#handleError(HttpServletRequest)
2023-10-14T23:28:30.727+05:30 DEBUG 7663 --- [io-8080-exec-10] m.m.a.RequestResponseBodyMethodProcessor : Using 'text/html', given [text/html, application/xhtml+xml, image/avif, image/webp, image/apng, application/xml;q=0.9, */*;q=0.8, application/signed-exchange;v=b3;q=0.7] and supported [text/plain, */*, application/json, application/*+json]
2023-10-14T23:28:30.728+05:30 DEBUG 7663 --- [io-8080-exec-10] m.m.a.RequestResponseBodyMethodProcessor : Writing ["<html><body><h2>Error Page</h2><div>Status code: <b>null</b></div><div>Exception Message: <b>N/A</b> (truncated)..."]
2023-10-14T23:28:30.729+05:30 DEBUG 7663 --- [io-8080-exec-10] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Exiting from "ERROR" dispatch, status 405
```

Comment: @RequestMapping path matches the form action in your HTML. ?

Comment: @UDID Yes. `th:action="@{/validateLogin}"` and `@RequestMapping(path = "/validateLogin", method = RequestMethod.POST)`

Comment: couple of thing. 1. is you debugger reaching to controller. as i can see you are returning `userName`. after that you must have to redirect ... something like that `return "redirect:/home";` (whatevr the page you are looking like landing page)

Comment: @UDID. It is not even reaching the Controller and throwing the exception.

Comment: Did you try removing the `action="#"` from the `<form>` in the login.html?

Comment: And please also show the HTML in the browser (using the devtools). Where is the login.html file located?

Comment: @dan1st. Yes, I had removed the `action="#"` and used `<form class="row g-4" th:action="@{/validateLogin}" method="post" th:object="${userInfo}">`.  The `login.html` is located in `/src/main/resources/static`.

Comment: The `static` directory is served 1:1 without being processed by Thymeleaf as stated in the answer.

Comment: Actually, i had set `spring.thymeleaf.enabled=false`, `spring.thymeleaf.check-template-location=false` in my `application.properties` for the time being, to get the basic thing to work first.

Comment: Remove all the properties related to thymleaf from application.properties.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have found the issue. There are multiple issues I have seen.

Don't access **logic.html** directly by keep it into `/static`. It doesn't work in that way.

---

**Note:** By default, **Thymeleaf** checks for `.html` files in the `/templates` directory only.

---

First of all, your **logic.html** should be in the `/templates` directory and not in the `/static` directory.

On the other hand, you were trying to tell thymeleaf that you will populate/bind values in an object `userInfo` in the **logic.html** but where did you get that object. You didn't create and pass that object anywhere.

So, you will need to create and pass that **Users** (`userInfo`) object from controller to that page.

Project Structure:

[image]

**pom.xml:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>3.1.4</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>demo-thymleaf</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>demo-thymleaf</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>
    <properties>
        <java.version>17</java.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

I have fixed your **login.html**:

```
<!--<div th:if="${param.error}">Invalid username and/or password.</div>-->
<form th:action="@{/validateLogin}" method="post" th:object="${userInfo}" class="row g-4">
   <div class="col-12">
      <label>Username<span class="text-danger">*</span></label>
      <div class="input-group">
         <div class="input-group-text"><i class="bi bi-person-fill"></i></div>
         <label>
         <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter Username" th:field="*{username}">
         </label>
      </div>
   </div>
   <div class="col-12">
      <label>Password<span class="text-danger">*</span></label>
      <div class="input-group">
         <div class="input-group-text"><i class="bi bi-lock-fill"></i></div>
         <label>
         <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter Password" th:field="*{password}">
         </label>
      </div>
   </div>
   <div class="col-sm-6">
      <div class="form-check">
         <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" id="inlineFormCheck">
         <label class="form-check-label" for="inlineFormCheck">Remember me</label>
      </div>
   </div>
   <div class="col-sm-6">
      <a href="#" class="float-end text-primary">Forgot Password?</a>
   </div>
   <div class="col-12">
      <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary px-4 float-end mt-4">login</button>
   </div>
</form>
```

Remove the unnecessary `action=#` from `<form>` tag.

I have prepared an Users class based on the info you have provided for testing.

```
public class Users {
    
    private String username;
    private String password;

    // constructor, getter and setters
}
```

To show success of `/validateLogin`, I have created a **success.html** too.

```
<body>
    <p>User Name: <strong th:text="${userInfo.username}"></strong></p>
    <p>Password: <strong th:text="${userInfo.password}"></strong></p>
</body>
```

Update the controller to something like this:

```
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ModelAttribute;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PostMapping;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView;

@Controller
public class AuthenticationController {
    
    @GetMapping("login-page")
    public ModelAndView loginPage(){
        ModelAndView view = new ModelAndView();
        view.setViewName("login");
        view.addObject("userInfo", new Users());
        return view;
    }

    @PostMapping("validateLogin")
    public ModelAndView validateLogin(@ModelAttribute Users userInfo){
       ModelAndView view = new ModelAndView();
       view.setViewName("success");
       view.addObject("userInfo", userInfo);
       return view;
    }
}
```

---

**Note:** You have to create and pass an `Users` model object/bean with no data via `ModelAndView` to the respective `login.html` file via thymeleaf before the page is parsed/opened.

Basically, it was expecting a plain target model object/bean for the bean name that you have used via `th:object` in the request attribute.

> By definition, the `th:object` attribute is used for binding the
> fields of the form to a model object.

In short, the thymeleaf doesn't have any idea from where `userInfo` will come as there is no model bean/object with that name exist when you declared `th:object="${userInfo}"`.

When you passed the field values from login page, `th:object` was trying to find the bean with the name in the spring container to the bind values but it couldn't find as you didn't pass any.

So, that's why, you got this error (which you probably missed to look at).

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Neither BindingResult nor plain target object for bean name 'userInfo' available as request attribute
```

To fix this, you will have to provide a bean initially. That's all, I can explain.

Output:

```
http://localhost:8080/login-page
```

[image]

Click on the Submit button. It will call `http://localhost:8080/validateLogin`

[image]

This will work.

You don't need to touch `application.properties` for thymeleaf unless you want to override default behaviour.

**Update:**

By looking at your controller code [here](https://github.com/sndpchatterjee07/campusconvene), this needs a complete correction:

**Change your controller code to this:**

```
import in.sandeep.campusconvene.model.Users;
import jakarta.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import jakarta.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
import org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.error.ErrorController;
import org.springframework.core.Ordered;
import org.springframework.http.HttpStatus;
import org.springframework.ui.Model;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.*;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.ViewControllerRegistry;

import java.io.IOException;

/**
 * The type RoutingController.
 *
 * @author sandeep
 * @version 1.0
 */
@RestController
public class RoutingController implements ErrorController {

    private static final String MAIN_APPLICATION_PATH = "/";
    private static final String LOGIN_VALIDATOR_PATH = "/validateLogin";
    private static final String ERROR_PATH = "/error";

    private ModelAndView modelAndView = new ModelAndView();

    /**
     * Gets Login Page.
     *
     * @return the Login Page
     */
    @RequestMapping(value = MAIN_APPLICATION_PATH, method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public ModelAndView getLoginPage() {
        modelAndView.setViewName("login");
        modelAndView.addObject("userInfo", new Users());
        return modelAndView;
    }

    /**
     * Handle Any Errors
     *
     * @return the Error Page
     */
    @RequestMapping(value = ERROR_PATH)
    public ModelAndView handleError() {
        modelAndView.setViewName("error_page");
        return modelAndView;
    }

    /**
     * Validate Login.
     *
     * @param request the request
     * @return the Home Page, if login is successful, else redirect to Login Page
     */
    @RequestMapping(value = LOGIN_VALIDATOR_PATH, method = RequestMethod.POST)
    @ResponseStatus(value= HttpStatus.OK)
    public ModelAndView validateLogin(@ModelAttribute Users userInfo){
        modelAndView.setViewName("welcomePage"); // REDIRECT TO USER HOME.
        modelAndView.addObject ("userInfo",userInfo);
        System.out.println ("ENTERED USERNAME => " + userInfo.getUsername ());
        System.out.println ("ENTERED PASSWORD => " + userInfo.getPassword ());
        return modelAndView;
    }
}
```

**Fixes:**

- I have removed all the `.html` word from all the `setViewName` method used. Use only the name of the html file in the `modelAndView.setViewName()`. For example: if you want to show *index.html*, then put `modelAndView.setViewName("index");`
- Set `modelAndView.addObject("userInfo", new Users())` in the `/` GET endpoint;

**Note:** Please create the **error_page.html** too. Your application is showing error that it's missing.

**Screenshot:**

**Welcome Back Page:**

[image]

**Login Page:**

[image]

Comment: I moved everything from `/resources/static` to `/resources/templates` and now when I access `http://localhost:8080/`, I encounter `jakarta.servlet.ServletException: Request processing failed: org.thymeleaf.exceptions.TemplateInputException: An error happened during template parsing (template: "class path resource [templates/login.html]")`

Comment: @SandeepChatterjee It shouldn't be happening.

Comment: @SandeepChatterjee There is a problem in login.html. See in the spring boot log.

Comment: @SandeepChatterjee I made username to userName in the login.html. I guess that' why you are facing that error.

Comment: @SandeepChatterjee use `username` instead of `userName` in login.html.

Comment: I am using `username` only.

Comment: @SandeepChatterjee Hmm. Can you provide your codebase via github to check the issue?

Comment: @SandeepChatterjee It's already working. Not sure on what have you done.

Comment: `https://github.com/sndpchatterjee07/campusconvene`. It does not work Anish.

Comment: I will check and revert Anish. Thank you.

Comment: @SandeepChatterjee I have added more explanation on why I added `modelAndView.addObject("userInfo", new Users())`.  Hope it helps.